# Factorising cubic with complex coefficients

Tags: complex-numbers, cubics

I was reading through something which progressed from the line:

$z^3  +  2(2 + i)z^2  +  (7 + 10i)z+ 6(1 + 2i) = 0$

To this line, factorised:

$(z-2) (z^2 - 2(1  +  i)z  +  3(1+2i)  ) = 0$

With no further information. Any advice as to how this step can be performed would be appreciated, as my own attempts don't appear to be working.

Comment: By inspection, $z=-2$ works, so $z+2$ is a factor. Long division gets the other factor.

Comment: No, $z=2$ does not work. However, $z=-2$ does.

Comment: There seems to be some muddled minus's ... I reckon the second line should be $(z \color{red}{+}2) (z^2 \color{red}{+} 2(1  +  i)z  +  3(1+2i)  ) = 0$

Comment: @Jo Fisher: "With no further information" -- unless finding the factorization was intended as an exercise for the student, it's possible that in the given context, the author simply provided the factorization with the assumption that the student could check it by simply expanding the product and regrouping the result.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[i]$, the ring of Gaussian integers.

Let $f = z^3  +  2(2 + i)z^2  +  (7 + 10i)z+ 6(1 + 2i)$.

Regarding $f$ as an element of $R[z]$, then since $R[z]$ is a UFD, and since $f$ is cubic and monic, it follows that $f$ is reducible in $R[z]$ if and only if $f$ has a root $r \in R$.

Then $r$ must be a factor the constant term $6(1+2i)$.

Noting that $1 + 2i$ is prime in $R$, a necessary condition is:
$$r \in \{u,2u,3u,6u,u(1+2i),2u(1+2i),3u(1+2i),6u(1+2i)\}$$
where $u$ is a unit of $R$, i.e., $u \in \{\pm 1,\pm i\}$.

Testing, we find $f(-2) = 0$, hence $z+2$ is a factor of $f$.

By Vieta's formulas, the sum of the roots of $f$ is $-2(2+i)$, and the product of the roots of $f$ is $-6(1+2i)$.

Hence, removing the known root $-2$, the sum of the other two roots is $$-2(2+i)-(-2) =-2(1+i)$$
and the product of the other two roots is 
$$\frac{-6(1+2i)}{-2}=3(1+2i)$$

Then by Vieta's formulas, the other two roots are roots of the quadratic polynomial
$$z^2+2(1+i)z+3(1+2i)$$
It follows that 
$$f = (z+2)(z^2+2(1+i)z+3(1+2i))$$

Answer (score 0):

$$z^3  +  2(2 + i)z^2  +  (7 + 10i)z+ 6(1 + 2i)=(z+2)(z+3-i)(z+1+3i)$$